# Disk shrink does not work on ESXi guests

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-workstation, thin-provisioning

EHLO everyone! My first post on the StackOverflow network :)

We're running some ESXi 5.0/vCenter infrastructure to host mainly Debian 6/amd64 guest systems with ext3 partitions and `open-vm-tools` compiled from source per [debian bug 471784](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=471784).

Got an issue that is seen being raised all around the internet, but without a conclusive answer given anywhere.

When trying to shrink a thin-provisioned disk in independent-persistent mode, with no snapshots, parents, clones whatsoever, I consistently get the following error:

```
root@linux64:~# vmware-toolbox-cmd disk list
Shrink disk is disabled for this virtual machine.

Shrinking is disabled for linked clones, parents of linked clones,
pre-allocated disks, snapshots, or due to other factors.
See the User's manual for more information.
```

(By the way, what are the "other factors", and which of the ton of white papers and technical manuals **is** the User's manual?:)

I know that I can stuff the partitions with zeros (in fact, I do use `shred -fuzn0` when deleting large files) then shut down the guest in question and use various methods like `vmkfstools`, cloning or vMotioning disks around in thin-provision mode, etc, but all of them either incur the downtime penalty for the guest being shirnked, or result in an unwarranted moving of data between datastores and/or hosts.

---

And the answer is: **No shrinking under ESX/ESXi (as of version 5).**

The [documentation](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmware-tools-cli.pdf) reads:

IMPORTANT **Shrinking disks is not allowed** under the following circumstances:

1. The virtual machine is hosted on an ESX/ESXi server.
   **ESX/ESXi Server** can shrink the size of a virtual
   disk only when a virtual machine is exported. The space occupied by
   the virtual disk on the ESX/ESXi server, however, does not change.
2. The virtual machine has a **Mac guest** operating
   system.
3. You **preallocated** all the disk space to the virtual
   disk when you created it.
4. The virtual machine contains a **snapshot**.
5. The virtual machine is a linked **clone** or the
   **parent** of a linked clone.
6. The virtual disk is an **independent** disk in
   **nonpersistent** mode.
7. The file system is a **journaling file system**, such
   as an **ext4, xfs, or jfs** file system.

No wonder there **is** an option to shrink in VMWare Workstation but not in vSphere client connected to an ESXi or vCenter instance.

Comment: could you show a value of the isolation.tools.diskShrink.disable key which can be found on the vmx file?

Comment: It wasn't there.

Adding isolation.tools.diskShrink.disable="false" didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmware-tools-cli.pdf
Page 13 :

Shrinking disks is not allowed under the following circumstances:

The virtual machine is hosted on an ESX/ESXi server. ESX/ESXi Server can shrink the size of a virtual disk
only when a virtual machine is exported. The space occupied by the virtual disk on the ESX/ESXi server,
however, does not change.

Comment: Sad but true...

Answer (score 18):

Actually, there is a way to shrink a VM on ESXi, although you need to shut down the VM for it. Here's how:

1. Zero all unused space inside the VM:

   `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1048576 of=/zero ; sync ; rm /zero`
2. Do the same with other mount points, swap partitions, etc.
3. Shut down the VM.
4. SSH to ESXi, and issue this command:

   `vmkfstools -K /vmfs/volumes/volumename/vmname/vmname.vmdk`

This will take some time... vmkfstools "punches holes" inside your VMDK, e.g. deallocates all blocks that are filled with zeros, effectively shrinking your VMDK.

Comment: For Windows, you can grab a copy of [Virtual Server 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserversystem/virtualserver/), extract the [Precompact.iso](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888760/en-us) file from it, it contains a Procompact.exe program that will zero all the unused disk pace in Windows.

Comment: vmkfstools are not working when the VM is on a NFS storage.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to shrink a VMDK in vSphere ESXi would be to export or to migrate/Storage vMotion to another datastore. I do this a lot with live servers that can handle a migration (not SQL or Exchange). A previous server admin built all VMs with Thick Provisioned disks. I migrate the VMs from one datastore to another and change the VMDK to thin-provisioned.

You can also do the vmkfstools if the server is offline.

Answer (score -1):

### **Shrinking disks is possible on ESXi.**

1. Find the large file and delete them.

   `find / -type f -size +50M`
2. Defragment (no need to un/remount anything). Ignore any errors. Some files like symlinks and device files can't be defragmented.

   `sudo e4defrag /`
3. Zero-fill all unused space so VMware knows it's indeed unused:

   `dd if=/dev/zero of=wipefile bs=1M; sync; rm wipefile`
4. Run the shrink operation:   If 4 fails, proceed to 5.

   `sudo vmware-toolbox-cmd disk shrinkonly`
5. Reboot the linux system with try option and edit the partition table with gparted. Shrink the root file system and delete & move swap partition near to root partition.
6. SSH to ESXi, and issue this command:

   `vmkfstools -K /vmfs/volumes/volumename/vmname/vmname.vmdk`
7. We need to edit the *.vmdk file. After the letters RW, defines the size of the VMware virtual disk (VMDK)

   *40 GB = 40 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 512  =  83886080*
8. Migrate it to another datastore to reflect the new size.