# How to reclaim disk space on ESXI 5.0

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi, thin-provisioning

I have a DELL R710 with ESXI 5.0. I've created a VM with 100GB thin provision. I deleted most of the data. Is it possible to shrink the VM folder on the ESXI?
thanks!
Dotan.

Answer (score 3):

Use Storage vMotion to move it to another datastore as a thick eager zeroed VMDK then move it back to the original location as a thin one.

Comment: what if I'm working with free ESXI 5 (no vmoition) with only one Datastore?

Comment: You could probably use Converter, drop it to a new file then reimport it? Never tried it to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

This answer explains how to do it https://serverfault.com/a/487550/15008

If you use a compressed filesystem eg. ZFS or thin provisioning over nfs then zeroing the blocks can be enough